# При компиляции кода выдает ошибку " error: 'class std::stack<int>' has no member named 'emplace' "

Tags: c++

```
int main()  
{
    stack <int> myStack;

    myStack.emplace(1);
    myStack.push(2);
    cout<<"the size is="<<myStack.size()<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Нужно компилировать с `-std=c++11`. Код правильный: [ideone](https://ideone.com/JY6jZm)

Comment: В таких случаях стоит указывать версию компилятора и операционную систему.

Comment: @Ariox: А операционная система-то тут при чем?

Comment: операционная система очень часто тоже важна - некоторые типы (стандартные!!) зависят от нее.

Comment: @KoVadim: Это как это? Реализация может учитывать "мнение" операционной системы при выборе параметров стандартных типов, но не более того.  И реализация может полностью игнорировать это "мнение". Так что никакой "зависимости" от операционной системы нет.

Comment: пол года не был, а люди такие же упертые. Посмотрите значение `sizeof(wchar_t)` на разных платформах и компиляторах. Можно начать с clang.

Comment: @KoVadim: По-прежнему не понимаю, к чему это тут.

Comment: wchar_t - стандартный тип? да. Берем компилятор одной и той же версии (clang или gcc). компилируем минимальный код для вывода sizeof(wchar_t) и наслаждаемся - он то два то четыре. Знание такого факта позволило ряду людей сохранить волосы на голове.

Comment: @Ariox, я за VS2010.

Comment: @KoVadim: И что? Решение все равно принимается компилятором. И если в случае символьного типа отладка на операционную систему является разумным и естественным решением, в случае других типов такая оглядка совершенно не нужна. Поэтому в упор не ясно, причем здесь операционная система, когда речь идёт о наличии метода в классе.